# I want to learn hacking but unable to connect to internet

Tags: php, wifi

I'm not sure if this is offtopic or not but i'll ask it anyway. Im 15 and i am into web design and development, working on PHP and MySQL. And i want to learn hacking but unfortunately my windows computer doesn't have access to the internet. There are some open public wifi connections but my pc's battery died, unfortunately.

And i think there are PROTECTED wifi connections that my adapter could have range to them, so i might use that as an advantage. So my first question is how can I take that advantage? And my second question: Is PHP and MySQL enough to start hacking? Thanks

Comment: "Hacking" is a extremely broad term. You should be a bit more specific. E.g. what you want to hack; ethical hacking or not; ... . And yes, this kind of question IS off topic here (http://security.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I'm just asking on how you started hacking. Not just that, I'm indirectly asking on how to hack WiFi WITH WINDOWS (7). Also put my second question into consideration. And why all those down votes?

Comment: Just take a look at the [help page](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your questions are off-topic and WAY too unspecific to answer in a meaningful way. There is no such person as a "hacker". One does not "hack" nor learn how to do so. One learns about software development and, over many, many years, learns how to spot and use [common] bugs. Forget what you see on television. The real world is **very** different and extremely complex compared to the common idea of a "hacker".

Comment: You have asked 2 completely unrelated questions: one is how to hack someone else's wifi connection. That question is off-topic here. Your second question is "Is PHP and MySQL enough to start hacking?" and the answer to that is short: yes, if you want to hack PHP and MySQL. Take a look around this site, and you will get a sense for the security field. You will also see great examples of the kinds of thinking you need to do in order to ask great questions.

Comment: @marstato you made me cry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remember that in most countries (if not all) accessing protected Wi-Fi networks without authorization is illegal. There are techniques you can use to do this, but I'm not going to describe them because it seems that you might use them to break the law, even if not knowingly. Learning ethical hacking is great, but you need to keep it ethical and legal.

Anyway, there are a lot of things you could do to access the Internet. For example, you could go to an internet cafè, or use a mobile data connection such as 3G from the computer (look up "tethering").

Of course, you might want to keep your expenses at a minimum. Note that you don't necessarily need to always use an Internet connection. A lot can be learned by installing  software like VMware or VirtualBox, and set up a couple of virtual machines. Basically, a virtual machine is a full-blown operating system which you can create *inside* the so-called "host system", in your case Windows 7. There are a lot of intentionally vulnerable virtual machines, that are designed to teach security concepts.

If I were you, I would somehow obtain an Internet connection (I mean legally) and download VirtualBox, a couple of vulnerable machines, and a few tutorials( How to set up virtual machine networks, what is a SQL injection, ...)  on a flash drive, go home and install all this stuff on your computer. After reading something you can start learning in a hands-on way!

By the way, you can use your knowledge of PHP and SQL in order to learn about the following vulnerabilities: SQL injection, remote and local file inclusion, directory traversal. These are basic flaws one can find (unfortunately) in many real world systems, so they are very important.

I also strongly suggest you to learn how to use Linux (install a Kali Linux VM as an attacking platform) and to learn at least a bit of Javascript. This way, you will also be able to exploit other vulnerabilities, such as cross-site scripting and CSRF.

Comment: wait a minute, I've tried to install Linux using Oracle Virtualbox and that also required some internet connection(even if I've downloaded the iso file). I'll try it again and again and see if it works. Thanks